# Issues with Obsidian Notetaking app

Tags: macos, app

On [this app](https://obsidian.md/), a note taking app called Obsidian, I am having issues trying to use CSS snippets, but the `.obsidian` folder is grayed out and I can't put anything in it.

I can see the files, just can't access them. In addition, headings are not working anymore, not sure if I turned off a setting for them.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you looked through the Obsidian support documents or pages, or elsewhere online for a solution? This isn't the wrong place to ask, but for an application with a pretty small user base, there's also a small chance someone with the experience you need will see your question, so looking at dedicated support sources should be part of your research.

Comment: Just edited. I've looked a lot of places already, this was my final resort.

Comment: Does [CSS snippets - Obsidian Help](https://help.obsidian.md/Extending+Obsidian/CSS+snippets) answer your question?

Comment: @DavidPostill the link tells me what to do, but not how to fix the issue I have. I don't believe it helps my problem.